# Calling @Async method from method which is @Schedule

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, scheduler

I have scheduler which listens to queue (Priorityqueue not like mq/jms) at every 1 second, once I got message that I am interested in I want to perform some logic.

So I have scheduler that runs every second, from that I am calling method which is annotated with @Async, assuming once I call that method scheduler will be back running with its interval.

Below is sample code, not sure I am using right pattern or advise. Idea is that once we have message we should not wait for prev processing, and we can have multiple threads processing it.

I am using Spring boot.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "1000", initialDelay = 10000)
public void startScheduler() {

   Message msg = queue.peek();

   if(msg!=null){
      doProcessing(msg);
   }

}


@Async
public void doProcessing(Message msg){
// Do processing
// May take 5 seconds.
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is not working, and it waits until doProcessing completes.

Comment: Spring AOP uses proxies, hence internal method calls don't pass through the proxy and hence `@Async` doesn't work. It has to be an external method call. Instead of hacking together your own solution, just use the spring messaging abstraction (which provides this and more out-of-the-box).

Comment: Ya, I agree. For now this can be done by publishing custom event too and then annotating listener with @Async.